# Spark SQL : Handling schema evolution

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, spark-avro

I want to read 2 avro files of same data set but with schema evolution

1. first avro file schema : {String, String, Int}
2. second avro file schema evolution : {String, String, Long}

(Int field is undergone evolution to long)
I want to read these two avro file to store in dataframe using sparkSQL.

To read avro files I am using 'spark-avro' of databicks
https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro

How to do this efficiently.

Spark version : 2.0.1
Scala. 2.11.8

PS. Here in example I have mentioned only 2 files but in actual scenario file is generated daily so there are more than 1000 such file.

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

use an union like

```
{string,string, [int, long]}
```

is a valid solution for your? it should allow read both new and old files.